# Value of Promise.all() after it is rejected, shows [''PromiseStatus'']: resolved if catch block is present

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have two promises, one rejected and other resolved. Promise.all is called. It executed the catch block of Promise.all as one of the promises is rejected.

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve('Promise 1 Resolved');
const promise2 = Promise.reject('Promise 2 Rejected');

const promise3 = Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Promise.all Resolved', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Promise.all REJECTED', error);
  })
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(promise1, promise2, promise3)
}, 200);
```

[image]

If I don't have the catch on Promise.all(), the value remains as Rejected, ie

```
const promise3 = Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Promise.all Resolved', data);
  })
```

Am I missing something about promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that its answer but I think I can clarify a bit more.

Please remember that each `then()` or `catch()` return a `Promise`. (If you don't have any explicit `return` in callback, both will return `Promise.resolve(undefined)`). Therefore after the promise has resolved, the value of entire promise chain will be the promise returned by last `then()`;
Example:

```
promise = Promise.resolve(1)
    .then(() => Promise.resolve(2))
    .then(() => Promise.resolve(3));
console.log(promise);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(promise)//Promise {<resolved>: 3}
}, 0)
```

`catch()` works in exactly like `then()`. The only difference is that its called on `rejected` promises rather then `resolved`.
In following example, I just replace all `resolve` by `reject` to demonstrate that.

```
promise = Promise.reject(1)
    .catch(() => Promise.reject(2))
    .catch(() => Promise.reject(3));
console.log(promise);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(promise)//Promise {<rejectd>: 3}
}, 0)
```

Now coming to your question. Value of `Promise.all()` is a rejected promise, since one of the promise in array is rejected. If you have a catch block in chain, control will go to that `catch` block which will return a `Promise.resolve(undefined)`. If you have no catch block in the chain, you will get what you have: a rejected promise.

Answer (score 3):

A `catch` on a Promise acts the same as a `try {} catch {}` block, in that you have captured the error state and the program will continue to function as normal.

That's why, when you omit the `catch`, your promise state is `"rejected"`.

If, after having caught the error, you want to return the promise state as rejected you need to return a rejected promise from the catch handler:

```
const promise3 = Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("REJECTED", error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
console.log(promise3); // [[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"
```

Similar to doing a `throw` inside a `try {} catch { throw; }` block

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.