# Function work incorrectly when using promise in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have routes like that:

```
router.get('/:projectid/, (req, res) => {
    testCase.getTestCaseDetail(req.params.projectid, req.params.testcaseid, req.params.snapshotId).then(testcaseData => {
      res.render('testCaseService', {
        title: 'Page',
        testcase: testcaseData,
        layout: 'project_layout',
      });
    });
  });
```

In the handler function, I have **getTestCaseDetail** function:

```
function getTestCaseDetail(projectId, id, snapshotId) {
  let testCaseId = parseInt(id);
  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    return testCaseSchema.aggregate([
      { $match: { 'projectId': projectId, 'testCaseId': testCaseId } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: snapshotInfoSchema.collection.collectionName,
          localField: testCaseObj.SERVICE_ID,
          foreignField: 'artifacts.id',
          as: 'services',
        },
      },
      { $unwind: '$services' },
      {
        $match: {
          'services.snapshot.id': snapshotId,
        }
      }
    ]).then(testCaseResult => {
      resolve(addTestCasesV2(testCaseResult, snapshotId));
    })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      })
  }));
}
```

and **addTestCasesV2** function

```
const addTestCasesV2 = function (testcases, snapshotId) {
  const result = [];
  let serviceTypeMapping;
  let serviceName;
  let testCase = {
    id: '',
    testCaseId: '',
    name: '',
    serviceName: '',
    serviceType: '',
    modifiedAt: '',
    testScripts: '',
    snapshotId: '',
    services: '',
    inputs: [],
    outputs: [],
  };
  let promiseInputResults, promiseOutputResults;
  const testcasesList = lodash.map(testcases, (tc) => {
    const artifacts = lodash.map(tc.services.artifacts, (art) => {
      if (art.id === tc.service_id) {
        serviceTypeMapping = art.processType.serviceTypeName;
        serviceName = art.name;
        if (!commonUtil.isUndefined(art.processParameters)) {
          if (!commonUtil.isUndefined(art.processParameters.input)) {
            promiseInputResults = lodash.map(art.processParameters.input, (ip) => {
              let classId = commonUtil.getArtifactId(ip.classId);
              return objectType.getObjectTypeByClassId(snapshotId, classId)
            });
          }

          if (!commonUtil.isUndefined(art.processParameters.output)) {
            promiseOutputResults = lodash.map(art.processParameters.output, (ip) => {
              let classId = commonUtil.getArtifactId(ip.classId);
              return objectType.getObjectTypeByClassId(snapshotId, classId)
            });
          }
        }
        testCase.id = tc.testCaseId;
        testCase.testCaseId = tc.testCaseId;
        testCase.name = tc.name;
        testCase.serviceName = serviceName;
        testCase.serviceType = serviceTypeMapping;
        testCase.modifiedAt = tc.modifiedAt;
        testCase.testScripts = tc.testScripts;
        testCase.snapshotId = snapshotId;
        testCase.services = tc.services;

        Promise.all(promiseInputResults).then(inputItems => {
          return testCase.inputs = inputItems;
        });

        Promise.all(promiseOutputResults).then(outputItems => {
          return testCase.outputs = outputItems;
        });

      }
    });
  });
  return testCase;
};
```

The inputs/outputs is an list of item, like that:
inputs:[
    {
     name: "test1",
     type: "String"
     },
     {
     name: "test2",
     type: "number"
     },
    ]

I have a problem with promise lifecycle, this is the current flow
1. Routes 
2. function getTestCaseDetail
3. resolve(addTestCasesV2(testCaseResult, snapshotId));
4. addTestCasesV2 ==> return testCase but without go to 2 promise.all functions
5. resolve(addTestCasesV2(testCaseResult, snapshotId));
6. Routes 
7. go back 2 promise.all functions
8. end at return testCase.outputs = outputItems;

Please see the image to more detail flow (the white number is current flow, the orange number is my expect flow)
[image]

Please advice me. Many thanks.

Comment: What does `objectType.getObjectTypeByClassId()` return?  Does it return a value or a promise?  Is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: And, `getTestCaseDetail()` contains a promise anti-pattern.  There is no need for wrapping it in a `new Promise()` in that function.  Just do `return testCaseSchema.aggregate(...).then(...)`.  Return the promise you already have.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem correct. If `testcases` is an array with more than one item, your `lodash.map` callback will be called `testcases.length` time. Each time overwriting `testCase.id` assigned in previous callback.

Anyways, I have corrected bits of your code to make it in run order that you wanted. I have logged `==step==` at various places for your help.

**First Function:**

```
function getTestCaseDetail(projectId, id, snapshotId) {
    let testCaseId = parseInt(id);
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        return testCaseSchema.aggregate([
            { $match: { 'projectId': projectId, 'testCaseId': testCaseId } },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: snapshotInfoSchema.collection.collectionName,
                    localField: testCaseObj.SERVICE_ID,
                    foreignField: 'artifacts.id',
                    as: 'services',
                },
            },
            { $unwind: '$services' },
            {
                $match: {
                    'services.snapshot.id': snapshotId,
                }
            }
        ]).then(testCaseResult => {
            console.log('=======STEP 1=======');
            resolve(addTestCasesV2(testCaseResult, snapshotId));//=======STEP 2=======
            console.log('=======STEP 5=======')

        })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            })
    }));
}
```

**Second function**

```
const addTestCasesV2 = function (testcases, snapshotId) {
    console.log('=======STEP 2=======')
    const result = [];
    let serviceTypeMapping;
    let serviceName;
    let testCase = {
        id: '',
        testCaseId: '',
        name: '',
        serviceName: '',
        serviceType: '',
        modifiedAt: '',
        testScripts: '',
        snapshotId: '',
        services: '',
        inputs: [],
        outputs: [],
    };
    let promiseInputResults, promiseOutputResults;

    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(()=>{
            console.log('=======STEP 3=======');
            const testcasesList = lodash.map(testcases, (tc) => {
                const artifacts = lodash.map(tc.services.artifacts, (art) => {
                    if (art.id === tc.service_id) {
                        serviceTypeMapping = art.processType.serviceTypeName;
                        serviceName = art.name;
                        if (!commonUtil.isUndefined(art.processParameters)) {
                            if (!commonUtil.isUndefined(art.processParameters.input)) {
                                promiseInputResults = lodash.map(art.processParameters.input, (ip) => {
                                    let classId = commonUtil.getArtifactId(ip.classId);
                                    return objectType.getObjectTypeByClassId(snapshotId, classId)
                                });
                            }

                            if (!commonUtil.isUndefined(art.processParameters.output)) {
                                promiseOutputResults = lodash.map(art.processParameters.output, (ip) => {
                                    let classId = commonUtil.getArtifactId(ip.classId);
                                    return objectType.getObjectTypeByClassId(snapshotId, classId)
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        testCase.id = tc.testCaseId;
                        testCase.testCaseId = tc.testCaseId;
                        testCase.name = tc.name;
                        testCase.serviceName = serviceName;
                        testCase.serviceType = serviceTypeMapping;
                        testCase.modifiedAt = tc.modifiedAt;
                        testCase.testScripts = tc.testScripts;
                        testCase.snapshotId = snapshotId;
                        testCase.services = tc.services;


                        /*=======FOLLOWING IS NOT REQUIRED=======*/
                        // Promise.all([promiseOutputResults]).then(outputItems => {
                        //     return testCase.outputs = outputItems;
                        // });

                    }
                });
            });
            return Promise.all([promiseInputResults,promiseOutputResults]);
        })
        .then(inputItems => {//array of resolved values
            console.log('=======STEP 4=======');
            testCase.inputs = inputItems[0];
            testCase.outputs = inputItems[1];
            return testCase;
        })
};
```

Now you can use following to extract testcase from first function:

```
getTestCaseDetail(myProjectId, id, mySnapshotId)
    .then(testCase=>console.log(testCase))
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t87jfquc/) for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have some questions: 1. This block code " .then(inputItems =>...." should put after Promise.all, Is that right? 2. After replace, I try to run, but the result is undefined in console.log(testCase)

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo 1. Promise.all([p1,p2) is a function which returns a new promise. This promise resolves to an [v1,v2]. So you chain to this promise using then(), like any other promise.  See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011826/value-of-promise-all-after-it-is-rejected-shows-promisestatus-resolved/51013221#51013221) for little bit more detail.

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo 2.Can you console.log() at step 4 to check what value  you are getting from as inputItems ?

Comment: Here is the log number and error: ===STEP 1====
=======STEP 2=======
===STEP 5====
=======STEP 3=======
=======STEP 4=======
internal/process/warning.js:18 (node:8508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: The error happens because we get item[0] of undefined: inputItems= undefined

Comment: oops...typo. replace Promise.all(...) by Promise.all([promiseInputResults,promiseOutputResults]). I forgot to put promises into array.

Comment: hmm, inputItems is still undefined.

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo Second function edited to put `return Promise.all()` in right place. Can you try now?

Comment: yeah, it works properly. Thanks for your support, I appreciate that. many thanks.

Comment: but I have a small issue, the  inputItems[0] is array promise not array object. it's different with Promise.all('single array')

Comment: `inputItems[0]`  and `inputItems[1]` will be the resolved values of `promiseInputResults`, `promiseOutputResults` respectively.

Comment: but  Promise.all(promiseInputResults).then(inputItems => {
          return testCase.inputs = inputItems;
        }); ==> it returns an array object

Comment: Dont get you. Can you edit in your question to tell what is the resolved value of promiseInputResults and promiseOutputResults . Also what exact value are you getting as inputItems?

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo Added a jsfiddle for you understanding.

Comment: Thanks, @dasfdsa. I try to run with these codes below:  return Promise.all(promiseInputResults).then(inputItems => {
    testCase.inputs = inputItems;
  })
    .then(() => {
      return Promise.all(promiseOutputResults).then(outputItems => {
        testCase.outputs = outputItems;
        return testCase;
      });
    }) ==> I can get list object instead list of promise, Is it correct?

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo no. Promise.all() expects array of promise. If there is just one promise, you dont need Promise.all.  `promiseInputResults.then(inputItems => {
    testCase.inputs = inputItems;
    return promiseOutputResults
}).then(outputItems => {
    testCase.outputs = outputItems;
    return testCase;
});
`

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo My advice is to understand the Promises first. It's a simple topic. Also, if you do so, you won't have to waste so much time debugging and you would be able to code confidently.

Comment: Thank you so much, @dasfdsa. Have a nice day :)