# recursion with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a collection in MongoDB like this

```
[
  {
    "classId": "1",
    "name": "Input",
    "definition": [
      {
        "property": [
          {
            "classId": "12",
            "name": "One"
          },
          {
            "classId": "8",
            "name": "Comment"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "classId": "8",
    "name": "CommentDetail",
    "definition": [
      {
        "property": [
          {
            "classId": "10",
            "name": "user"
          },
          {
            "classId": "10",
            "name": "message"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "classId": "10",
    "name": "String",
    "definition": []
  },
  {
    "classId": "12",
    "name": "Int",
    "definition": []
  }
]
```

Based on db above, I have a model to display
data = {
          name:'',
          template: ''
      }

With classId=1, the expectation result is

```
   {
      "Name": "Input",
      "temlate": "{['One': 'Int','Comment': ['user': 'String','message':'String']]}"
}
```

I try to using recursive promise to implement it. When property[] is empty, the result will be return.

Here is my function:

```
const getObjectTypeByClassId = (snapshotId, artifactId, objectType) => {

  return artifactDetailModel.find({
      'snapshotId': snapshotId,
      'artifactId': artifactId
    })
    .then(data => {
      let artifact = data[0];
      let definition;
      let definitionData = {};

      return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
          definition = artifact.data.teamworks.twClass[0].definition[0];
          if (!lodash.isUndefined(definition.property)) {
            const listOfProperty = definition.property;
            for (let property of listOfProperty) {
              classId = commonUtil.getArtifactId(property.classRef[0]);
              if (!lodash.isUndefined(classId)) {
                return getObjectTypeByClassId(snapshotId, classId, objectType);
              }
            }
          } else {
            definitionData.nameType = artifact.data.teamworks.twClass[0].elementAttribute.name;
            definitionData.classId = artifact.data.teamworks.twClass[0].elementAttribute.id;
            definitionData.template = bpmMapping.objectType[artifact.data.teamworks.twClass[0].elementAttribute.name];

            return objectTypeModel.create(definitionData)
              .then(obj => {
                const response = {
                  name: objectType.name,
                  isArrayOf: objectType.isArrayOf,
                  nameType: obj.nameType,
                  template: obj.template,
                }
                return response;
              })
          }

        })
    })
}
```

Run with my function, the response is

```
data: {
  Name: Input
  temlate: user: String,
}
```

Please advice me.

Comment: its because you return in your loop. consider using `async`/`await` to simplify your code

Comment: @DanielA.White  Using async/await in loops is non-blocking?

Comment: @dasfdsa: Could you please advise me?

Comment: I tried to. I tried to read your code but you haven't explained your problem well. Can you make your outputs more clear: `input: id=1
==> output: 
      Input:[
    {IsActive[Output:String]},
    {One: Int}
    ]
or input: id=2 
==> output: {Output:String}` , also please clarify what does your `createObjectType` does.

Comment: @dasfdsa: I just updated my post, please help me review. It relate with the my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056611/function-work-incorrectly-when-using-promise-in-node-js?noredirect=1#comment89124215_51056611

Comment: List of `json`s you provided isn't correct. There shouldn't be `=` or `;`. Also, expectation result is not correct json or js object

Comment: @dasfdsa: yes, its my mistake. I just update the data with correct jon format

Comment: In `expectation result` why `One` is `int` and why `comment` is `['user': 'String','message':'String']`?

Comment: @dasfdsa:  'One' has classId=12, so we need to loop in db to find object with classId =12 ==> result:: name= Int, and defenition[] is empty ==> I stop here. otherwise, I continue to loop in db. The Comment  work same logic with One

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution from a guy on the internet. it works well. Thanks, @Cuong Quach

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var database = 'testdequy';
var collection = 'classes';
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/" + database, function (err, db) {

    findDetails("1").then((r) => {
        console.log("r>>>", r);
    })

    function findDetails(classId) {
        var results = { Name: "", Template: "" };
        var template = {};
        return new Promise((main_resolve, reject) => {
            process(template, "" , classId)

            var works = 0;
            function process(parent, childKey, objectId) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    db.collection(collection).find({ classId: objectId })
                        .toArray((err, docs) => {
                            if (results.Name == "") {
                                results.Name = docs[0].name;
                            }
                            let objectItem;
                            if (childKey == "")
                                 objectItem = parent;
                            else
                                 objectItem = parent[childKey];

                            console.log("\ndocs", docs[0], objectId, objectItem)
                            if (docs[0].definition.length == 0 || docs[0].definition[0].property == undefined) {
                                let name  = docs[0].name;
                                    parent[childKey] = name;
                                console.log("\nNo child", docs[0],parent, objectItem, docs[0].name)
                                resolve(0);

                            } else {

                                docs[0].definition[0].property.forEach((item) => {
                                    works++;
                                    //console.log("item", item)
                                    let id = item.classId;
                                    let name = item.name;
                                    objectItem[name] = {};
                                    process(objectItem, name, id).then((len)=>{
                                        works--;        
                                        if(len == 0 && works == 0) main_resolve(template);
                                    })

                                })
                                resolve(docs[0].definition[0].property.length)
                            }
                        })
                })
            }
        })

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it to some extent, but wasn't able to get it right. Plus your expected output is not the valid JSON `"temlate": {[]}` doesn't make sense. 
It has nothing to do with `Promise`. You have to DFS you db array and created expected output. Here is what I have donup tillll now, you can think along those lines. But this is far from the solution.

```
let mainArray = [
    {
        "classId": "1",
        "name": "Input",
        "definition": [
            {
                "property": [
                    {
                        "classId": "12",
                        "name": "One"
                    },
                    {
                        "classId": "8",
                        "name": "Comment"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "classId": "8",
        "name": "CommentDetail",
        "definition": [
            {
                "property": [
                    {
                        "classId": "10",
                        "name": "user"
                    },
                    {
                        "classId": "10",
                        "name": "message"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "classId": "10",
        "name": "String",
        "definition": []
    },
    {
        "classId": "12",
        "name": "Int",
        "definition": []
    }
]

function dfs(root, createdRoot,  fn, level) {

    fn(root,createdRoot, level);

    if(root.definition)/*if definition exists => keep traversing*/
    root.definition[0].property.forEach(function (child) {
        createdRoot.template = createdRoot.template || [];
        let tempObj = {};
        let lookupObj = lookupByClassId(child.classId);
        tempObj[child.name] = lookupObj.name;
        createdRoot.template.push(tempObj);
        dfs(child,tempObj, fn, level + 1);
    });
    else /*if definition doesn't exist, look into the array*/
    {
        createdRoot.template = lookupByClassId(root.classId);
    }
}

function lookupByClassId(classId){
    for(let i=0;i<mainArray.length;++i){
        let element =mainArray[i]
        if(element.classId == classId)
            return element;
    }
}


let root = lookupByClassId(1);
createdRoot ={};

function func1(root, createdRoot, level) {
    createdRoot.name = root.name;
    console.log(root.classId);
}

dfs(root, createdRoot, func1, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. I just updated the answer, please have a look.